# Visualizing two different datasets amicably when they are measuring two different things

Tags: arcgis-online, spatial-statistics, comparison, story-map, swipe

I am working on a story map in AGOL that is comparing the percentage of a population that lives in a house that has been deemed transit dependent versus the concentration of a population that lives in a house that has been deemed transit dependent. Each of these are done by census tract.

The purpose of the story map is to show that while there are areas that have been deemed by the area density map as not as significant because of the overall size of the census tract there are areas that have significant portions that are not occupied by residents, but the overall percentage is high.

How do I ensure that these two scales are evenly distributed while at the same time retaining the simplicity of user interpretation (not using a standard deviation scale)

The below image is the scale that I am currently working with that measures percentage of the population versus residents by square mile.

[image: Current Legend Scale]

Comment: Have you tried creating a relationship map? https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/what-is-a-relationship-map/

Comment: I just put together this map using colors and sizes, but I still really like using a swipe map to describe this a bit better.

Comment: If you can share the storymap, it might allow people to give you more useful feedback.